# What does this Perl XML filter look like in Python?

Tags: python, regex, perl, email, curl

```
curl -u $1:$2 --silent "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom" | perl -ne 'print "\t" if /<name>/; print "$2\n" if /<(title|name)>(.*)<\/\1>/;'
```

I have this shell script which gets the Atom feed with command-line arguments for the username and password. I was wondering if this type of thing was possible in Python, and if so, how I would go about doing it. The atom feed is just regular XML.

Comment: The Perl itself does not make sense. The statement `print "$2\n" if /(.*)/;` says 'print the second capture group in the regex' but there is only a single capture group there. There will never be a second match group...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python does not lend itself to compact one liners quite as well as Perl. This is primarily for three reasons:

1. With Perl, whitespace is insignificant in almost all cases. In Python, whitespace is very significant.
2. Perl has some helpful shortcuts for one liners, such as `perl -ne` or `perl -pe` that put an [implicit loop](http://www.perl.com/pub/2004/08/09/commandline.html) around the line of code.
3. There is a [large body a cargo-cult](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/perl-one-liners-explained-part-one/) Perl one liners to do useful things.

That all said, this python is close to what you posted in Perl:

```
curl -u $1:$2 --silent "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom" | python -c ' 
import sys
for s in sys.stdin:
    s=s.strip()
    if not s: print '\t',
    else: print s
'
```

It is a little difficult to do better because, as stated in my comment, the Perl you posted is incomplete. You have:

```
perl -ne 'print "\t" if //; print "$2\n" if /(.*)/;'
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
LINE:
while (<>) {
  print "\t" if //;         # print a tab for a blank line
  print "$2\n" if /(.*)/;   # nonsensical. Print second group but only 
                            # a single match group defined...
}
```

**Edit**

While it is trivial to rewrite that Perl in Python, here is something a bit better:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
import sys

def get_XML_doc_stdin(f):
    return xml.dom.minidom.parse(f)

def get_tagged_data2(tag, index=0):    
    xmlData = dom.getElementsByTagName(tag)[index].firstChild.data
    return xmlData

data=sys.stdin.read()
dom = parseString(data)

ele2=get_tagged_data2('title')
print ele2

count=int(get_tagged_data2('fullcount'))
print count,"New Messages:"

for i in range(0,count):
    nam=get_tagged_data2('name',i)
    email=get_tagged_data2('email',i)
    print "  {0}: {1} <{2}>".format(i+1,nam,email)
```

Now save that in a text file, run `chmod +x` on it, then:

```
curl -u $1:$2 --silent "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom" | 
/path/pythonfile.py
```

It produces this:

```
Gmail - Inbox for xxxxxxx@gmail.com
2 New Messages:
  1: bob smith <bob@smith.com>
  2: Google Alerts <googlealerts-noreply@google.com>
```

**edit 2**
And if you don't like that, here is the Python 1 line filter:

```
curl -u $1:$2 --silent "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom" |python -c ' 
import sys, re
for t,m in re.findall(r"<(title|name)>(.*)<\/\1>",sys.stdin.read()):
    print "\t",m
'
```

Comment: just fixed the perl - a lot of it was not displaying...oddly. i find that the <pre> tag has difficulty with

Comment: '<'s inside of it but if you could update your answer that would be cool

Answer (score 1):

You may use an "URL opener" from the `urllib2` standard Python module with a handler for authentication. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import getpass
import sys
import urllib2

def main(program, username=None, password=None, url=None):

    # Get input if any argument is missing
    username = username or raw_input('Username: ')
    password = password or getpass.getpass('Password: ')
    url = url or 'https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom'

    # Create password manager
    password_mgr = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
    password_mgr.add_password(None, url, username, password)

    # Create HTTP Authentication handler and URL opener
    authhandler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr)
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(authhandler)

    # Fetch URL and print content
    response = opener.open(url)
    print response.read()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(*sys.argv)
```

If you'd like to extract information from the feed too, you should check how to parse [Password-Protected Feeds](http://www.feedparser.org/docs/http-authentication.html) with `feedparser`.